# Proofreading a LyX document

Tags: pdf, lyx, editors

After writing a document in LyX I often convert to `pdf` and print for proofreading.  The annoying part is that words that appear at a certain place in the pdf tend to appear in different locations in LyX (because LyX is not WYSIWYG).  This forces me to make corrections on paper, then do "find" with a specific set of words to find the part of the paper I want to correct.  Are there any tricks to doing this better? Is there a way to make LyX display things more in accordance with what they will look like in the pdf in terms of location?

Per the answer below: I try to get it working with okular and lyx 2.0.5 on windows 7.  It does not not seem to work. Could someone follow up and give me detailed step by step instructions?

Answer (score 6):

LyX supports forward and reverse search between the PDF and the LyX editor via synctex. This means that by a (PDF-Viewer–dependent) click or command you can navigate from the PDF directly to the corresponding line (or at least paragraph) in LyX.

The settings to set up this depend a lot on the LyX version, PDF viewer and OS in use. The details are described in the [LyX wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX).

Comment: could you please be more specific? i use adobe pdf viewer as my pdf viewer. i have followed the instructions in the wiki but not sure how to make this operational still..

Comment: i use lyx 2.0 btw.

Comment: i have also installed okular.. attempting for that to work

Comment: i get the error: "could not open $$o" in okular

Comment: See the manual Help > Additional features. I don't know anything about forward search so I can't help you, but from what I've read it's hard to get right because it's application-dependent and the applications are often changing their settings.

Comment: @Alex: I used to get it running on Windows and OS X, even though that is a while ago. Please provide exact details about OS and version, LyX and version, and PDF viewer. Maybe I or some other could help you with more specific instructions.

Comment: @Alex: For Adobe Reader as viewer, the situation unfortunately seems to be a bit hopeless: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38983/using-synctex-with-adobe-acrobat-reader However, with other PDF readers it should work.

Comment: @Daniel: thank you, just updated by question.. maybe someone can jump in.