# LaTeX editor with inverse search and on the fly output preview

Tags: editors, forward-inverse-search

I have just formatted my HDD and I am trying to build up my system again. I am running both Windows Vista and Ubuntu. I am planning to install MiKTeX 2.9 - TeX Live and I am in search of an editor.

So far I was using TeXniccenter. It isn't bad, but I would like-if possible-to use an editor that will have an inverse search in either Adobe Reader or in Nitro. So far I could use inverse search in TeXniccenter with Sumatra, but it's not a pdf viewer that suits my taste!

I would also like it to have an "on-the-fly" change in a preview output. What I mean is, when I change something in the `.tex` file, to be changed on-the-fly on a preview output, similar to Texmaker. I've heard that something like that can be done in Geany, but I've never managed to do it on Ubuntu, which would the ideal case, because someone has to use only one editor in either OS.

Do you think that an editor with the two above features exists?
Any suggestions, are more than welcome!

Comment: SyncTeX very likely won't work with Adobe Reader, don't know about Nitro: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38983/using-synctex-with-adobe-acrobat-reader This doesn't have anything to do with the editor. TeXmaker doesn't have any real-time update as far as I know. Here's a question about real-time compiling: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633/is-there-any-way-to-get-real-time-compilation-for-latex Gummi for example, would do this in Linux.

Comment: With Emacs you can automatically run the *TeX processor whenever your source code is saved.

Comment: Adobe Reader locks the pdf files which have to be unlocked before the pdf be updated. `WinEdt` has scripts to do that, but it's a shareware editor. On Windows systems, SumatraPdf is definitely the best pdf viewer for TeX users (installation directory: 11 Mo vs 175 Mo for Adobe Reader!).

Answer (score 1):

TexStudio is the editor you are looking for:

http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Maybe you want to flesh out that answer of yours a bit, so it is not only a "link-only answer".

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty simple and useful (at least for me)

http://gummi.midnightcoding.org