# PDF inverse search in acrobat revisited

Tags: pdf, forward-inverse-search, acrobat

I've found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38983/using-synctex-with-adobe-acrobat-reader) about impossibility of inverse search with acrobat, but it is from 2012 so I decided to post in case there is some update.

Does anybody know if situation has changed in any way? Any hope for inverse search from acrobat?

Comment: From what I understand of the matter this is not supported, because Adobe doesn't implement `synctex` which is necessary to inverse search the source file.

Comment: Well there might be some other solutions. E.g. I remember winedt was doing inverse search from dvi for quite a while and I believe before any synctex files appeared in my outputs.

Comment: You should remember that DVI and PDF are very distinct filetypes, so not having seen `synctex` with DVI doesn't mean it isn't necessary for PDF. Inverse search takes two things, some kind of database (either as separate file or inline comments) that relates a position in the document to a position in the source, and a piece of software that actually reads this database and performs an action based on that info. As long as Adobe doesn't implement the latter, inverse search will not work.

Comment: I see. That's sad :(

Comment: Not that sad, really. Just another reason to avoid Adobe's software 99% of the time ;).

Comment: @cfr Well I would even gladly avoid pdf for that matter, were it not so widespread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sad answer is, that situation is unchanged from about two years ago, the time Joseph Wright answered the linked question [Using SyncTeX with Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38983/using-synctex-with-adobe-acrobat-reader).

As hugovdberg writes inverse search would only be possible if Adobe would implement the SyncTeX feature, but this was until now not the case.

Comment: It might be possible to have a package that creates a bunch of hyperlink to the original text file (and line numbers). See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132867/1871 . I managed to create this links manually as a proof of concept That would be independent of `Synctex` but I agree it will 1) polute the resulting PDF with mouse-active zones and 2) opening specific files and line numbers from PDF. while possible, can be a pain to set up.